# Do medical doctors publish academic papers and write grant proposals?

Tags: publications, tenure-track, medicine

I know that medical doctors affiliated with universities can teach at the medical schools as professors and write chapters in textbooks.  But do medical doctors with a university affiliation also have to publish academic papers and write successful grant proposals, in order to be promoted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Medical schools generate large proportions of the grant funding at many major research universities. Most faculty (except possibly research-only faculty) in medical schools have an M.D. degree. Research expectations for clinical-only faculty are often meager but faculty that conduct research at major universities often need to PI large grants to receive tenure.